# Grouping ASP.net server controls to modify properties without referencing them by name

Tags: c#, asp.net, servercontrols

I'm trying to dynamically set the `Visible` property of multiple boxes, panels, buttons etc. from my codebehind for an aspx page.  I was wondering if there is a way to group server controls into some logical group so that you could do something like this pseudo-code:

```
foreach(c in controlgroup) {
    c.Visible = value
}
```

The reason being is that the page displays different kinds of options depending on an ID parameter in the URL.  I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451442/grouping-controls-asp-net) but I'm wondering if there's another way to do it than by using user controls?

**Edit**:
It would be nice if I could set the group on the aspx page rather than having to still add each control manually..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can group them by building a `List<Control>`, and then loop over it.

```
var controlList = new List<Control>();
controls.Add(someTextBox);
controls.Add(someOtherTextBox);
// etc.

// elsewhere
foreach (var control in controlList)
    control.Visible = false;
```

Of course, if you were working on controls all held in a common container (form, panel, etc.), you could simply loop over its control collection.

```
foreach (var control in theContainer.Controls)
    control.Visible = false;
```

And in this trivial example, making the container itself invisible would do the job. Beyond these simple methods, there is not a way to group controls *that I know of,* but I'm not often dealing with the UI.

Comment: in second case it's quite enough to set Visible=false on container control

Answer (score 2):

If you put them in a container of some sort, like a Panel or PlaceHolder, you can do something like this:

```
List<WebControl> ctrlList = PlaceHolder1.Controls.Cast<WebControl>().ToList();
foreach (WebControl ctrl in ctrlList)
{
    ctrl.Visible = false;
}
```

You can shorten the above example by doing this:

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Cast<WebControl>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.Visible = false);
```

If you wanted to, you could create properties that return lists of different types of controls:

```
public List<TextBox> InputList
{
    get
    {
        return PlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this and depends on your specified project/needs.

You could wrap a group of items in a `<asp:Panel>` and then use the Children collection.

You could give the controls special ids like, group1_name, group2_name etc and loop the page's child control collection

You could add attributes to your controls like `<asp:Button ... myGroup="1" />` and loop the Page's child controls then check the attributes.

You could add a base class and monitor the children collection and use the .Tag property to assign groups

and on and on...